# Issue Refreshing excel pivot table using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to refresh excel pivot table using openpyxl library.

data sheet

[image]

result sheet

[image]

If I update values in data sheet, the pivot table in result sheet gets updated only when I reopen the excel file. I cannot get the updated value in my **new_df** variable of my python code.
I need to use the **new_df** variable for in my further code. So, reopening the file to refresh the data won't help me.

Is there any other workaround to resolve my issue in **Linux** machine?

Here is the code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook("test_excel_file2.xlsx")
ws = wb["result"]
pivot= ws._pivots[0]
pivot.cache.enableRefresh = True
pivot.cache.refreshOnLoad = True
wb.save(excel_filepath)

new_df = pd.read_excel("test_excel_file2.xlsx", sheet_name=calc_sheet)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Openpyxl edits the XML files that make up an Excel file. It does not [re]calculate formulas. These things happen when the workbook/sheet is opened in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that - openpyxl just edits the Excel file, all the calculations are done by Excel itself. You can automate the launching/closing of Excel though so it recalculates the formulas or do the calculations in Python script and edit the desired cells with openpyxl.